# "just a scout's taste"--meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the game *[Shantae: Risky's Revenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shantae:_Risky%27s_Revenge)*, there's this scene where one of the characters suggests Shantae, the main protagonist, should try (eat) a puppy.

> [Rotty] Here. You have GOT to try one of these!
>   [Shantae] Gasp! This is someone's pet!
>   [Shantae] Put it back where you found it!
>   [Rotty] Come on! **Just a scout's taste!**
>   [Shantae] Nevermind. I'll return this puppy myself.

I think "just a taste" means something like "try a little", right? But what about *scout's*? What does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `just a taste` means just a little, even as little a bite as possible.

But `scout's taste` is not a known collocation or saying. Maybe it's based on someone or something in the game story?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything even remotely connected with scouts in this game. I've found this video (https://youtu.be/S878n99TO8Q?t=115) on YouTube (1:55 - 2:28) maybe it would shed more light on the issue.